# How to make string.contains work with a list

Tags: vb.net, string, contains

So I have this bot I'm making for someone that filters out curse words in a skype chat.
Instead of making it so my code is really long I want it so there is a huge list of curse words already loaded for example:

```
If Msg.Contains("swear1") Or Msg.Contains("swear2") Then
    c.SendMessage("{---------Bot----------}" + vbNewLine + "DO NOT SWEAR!" + vbNewLine + "{-------------------------------------------}")
End If
```

I've tried creating an array and a string holding multiple values and didn't really work out too good as it didn't execute the function after someone said the trigger word. So I wanted to know if there is a way I can hold a huge list of curse words in one whatever without using

```
Msg.Contains("swear1")
```

Or

```
Msg.Contains("swear2")
```

etc etc, so everything would be held in one bit.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You use a Collection of Swear words and check the string against that. The `.Any` method takes the array and internally creates a For/loop with the `word` being the variable name for this loop and represents each string in the the array to test with our `SwearWords.Contains(word)` boolean expression, and if any of the expressions equates to `True` then it returns `True`.

```
Dim swearWordExists As Boolean = False
Dim msg As String = "swear1! has a swear word with extra text but still found"
Dim SwearWords As New List(Of String)
' fill it with your swear words
SwearWords.AddRange(New String() {"swear1", "swear2", "etc..."})
' then
If Not msg.Contains(" ") Then
  ' msg only has one word so check it
  If SwearWords.Contains(msg) OrElse SwearWords.Any(Function(words) msg.Contains(words)) Then
    swearWordExists = True
  End If
Else
  Dim words = Regex.Split(msg, "\W")
  If Not words.Any(Function(word) SwearWords.Contains(word)) Then
    If words.Any(Function(word) SwearWords.Any(Function(swear) word.Contains(swear))) Then
      swearWordExists = True
    End If
  Else
    swearWordExists = True
  End If
End If
If swearWordExists Then
  MessageBox.Show("Why are you swearing?")
End If
```

Comment: Could you be more specific as to how I fill the list with my swear word strings. Kind of a noob

Comment: One at a time `SwearWords.Add("Damn")` or do you have a another place where you store a bunch of them?

Comment: Can I not just make them all in one line SO I can save alot of space?

Comment: @Matty11233 `Dim sw As New List(Of String) From {"swear1", "swear2", "swear3"}` and to add more: `sw.AddRange({"swear4", "swear5"})`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks alot, working perfect sorry I can't your reply but still thanks a bumch

Comment: @AndrewMorton, good point, that would change the algorithm a bit.

Comment: @OneFineDay I suggest using `Regex.Split(s, "\W")` to do the split.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, what is the difference?

Comment: @OneFineDay `\W` (n.b. uppercase W) in a regex represents a non-word character, so it will split on things like punctuation too - there's a fair chance a word will end at a full stop or comma, not just a space, and you can't expect users to always following their punctation with a space. There are reasons that bad-word lists aren't always that useful, just ask the residents of [Scunthorpe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: @AndrewMorton, again another fine point! I'll let the OP decide that - not going to steal your good ideas for my answer. I wonder what happened to the OP? They have not chimed in awhile.

Comment: @OneFineDay Go for it! It's a right pain in the... errr... to get a filter like that to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could condense your code like this

```
Dim swears = New List(Of [String])() From {"swear1", "swear2"}
If Regex.IsMatch("[your message]", String.Format("({0})", String.Join("|", swears))) Then
    MsgBox("Don't swear!")
End If
```

Where swears would be your list of all swears you don't want someone to say

What it does is it takes all strings in 'swears' and puts them into this format: (swear1|swear2) then regex will see if your message contains either 'swear1' or 'swear2' et cetera if you have more.

Answer (score 0):

An easy but not super performant way would be to convert your string to a list then use the list intersect functionality

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb910215(v=vs.90).aspx